# application with number of activities having different orientations

Tags: android, tabs, screen-orientation

In our application i have four tabs and on first tab m showing three option on click of first tab. Three option are:- 1) camera view. 2) Map View 3) ListView.

I need whole applicatin in portrait mode except mapview and camera view. We need to display these view in porttrait mode as well as in landscape mode. I have set android:screenOrientation="portrait" in manifest file for tab activity.

I have no idea how i can change at run time for different activities, different-2 orientation in tabview.

Help will be appriciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

hi u can use this code...

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call this method at any time:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: @ Dredel thanks for reply. I have done with same. we have to implement two specific activities in portrait and landscape, others need to be in portraint mode. For this I have set android:screenOrientation="portrait for each activity instead mapview and cameraview in manifest file. I have removed this paremeter from tabactivity. Now it is changing orientation for all activities in landscape and portrait mode.

Comment: are you saying you are trying the code above and it's not working? If that is so, then you're doing something wrong. If in each activity's onResume method you add this code, then they will re-orient themselves every time they gain focus. Also, as @Akki points out, you can add the screenOrientation attribute to the individual manifest entries for each Activity to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

> I need whole applicatin in portrait mode except mapview and camera
>   view. We need to display these view in porttrait mode as well as in
>   landscape mode. I have set android:screenOrientation="portrait" in
>   manifest file for tab activity.

You need to set `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in manifest for each activity which are being displayed in Tabs.

or you can do it in your java file like [Dr. Dredel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59947/dr-dredel) suggested for each activity